# Firebase Swift iOS: "Cannot get flag for unregistered flag" error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics

I am using Firebase analytics with Xcode and iOS. Only recently, firebase started printing this error, sometimes spamming it tens, if not hundreds of times in a row:

```
9.6.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800014] Cannot get flag for unregistered flag. SDK name, flag name: app_measurement, session_stitching_token_feature_enabled
```

The app works fine, events are logged fine. What is causing this error?